# Converting date in field-created.html.twig

Tags: 9

node-created.html.twig to override some html.
That works fine. Although the date is being displayed as `Thu, 04/28/2022 - 11:39` which I want to be something like `May 2, 2023`. Is this possible within this piece of twig code?

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'field',
    'field--name-' ~ field_name|clean_class,
    'field--type-' ~ field_type|clean_class,
    'field--label-' ~ label_display,
    'created-label',
  ]
%}
<span{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {%- for item in items -%}
    {{ item.content }}
  {%- endfor -%}
</span>
```

Comment: That is not the template you want.  You probably want the field template for the date field for whatever node/content type you want to change it for.  Please update your question with more details about what you are trying to do.  Also, note that you can edit how dates are displayed without any coding at `/admin/config/regional/date-time`.

Comment: @PatrickKenny It's just the authored on field, which is the exact template I currently use. And I only need to edit the date format that is shown for a specific node.

Answer (score 0):

As a learning experience

I suggest you look at the twig date function
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html

```
{{ field_crated|date("m/d/Y") }}
  or 
 {{ crated|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

then also if that does not work

```
 function THEME_preprocess_field__node(&$variables) {
```